# What is wrong in this MATLAB expression?

Tags: matlab, plot, trigonometry, exponential

I need to implement the function

```
5cos((x^4)/3)tan(exp(0.2x))cos(ln(4x))
```

in MATLAB and plot it inside domain [-PI, PI] with 1000 elements.

```
x = linspace(-pi, pi, 1000);
y = 5*cos((x.^4)/3).*cos(log(x*4)).*tan(exp(x*0.2));
plot(x,y);
```

This is what i did. It gives me [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIEPq.png) plot, but this plot is incorrect. According to many online plotting tools (Wolfram, GrapSketch, Rechneronline...) the plot should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgnNO.png).

Why MATLAB plots it so different? Is the code wrong?

Comment: Plot it with the same axis scaling and it will look the same. You MATLAB plot shows a much larger section of the plot and you probably don't recognize the small piece you see in GraphSketch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The positive part of the plot is the same between the two plots you posted. Just zoom in into your matlab plot adding

```
axis([-pi pi -50 50])
```

after `plot(x,y)`.
[image: Figure zoomed]

Not sure why your "target" plot isn't showing the negative part of the plot.